# How do I find/delete an apostrophe(') in bash syntax for a GitHub Action Workflow?

Tags: bash, github-actions

In my organization, we have a GitHub Action that creates a new issue when a PR is merged into the main branch. The purpose of this issue is to determine whether or not the PR that merged needs updated user documentation.

I ran into an issue where the GitHub Action fails to create an issue if the title of the PR contains an apostrophe (e.g. PR title: Don't enable xyz)

The GitHub action lives in a yml file and uses bash syntax for the commands. My current command looks like this:

```
  - name: create-issue
    id: create-issue
    run: |
      title='${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}'

      echo "title should be ${title//\"/\'}"

      writer=${{ steps.get-writer.outputs.writer }}

      echo "writer should be $writer"

      echo "test"

      pr_number=${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}

      data=$( cat << EOT
      {
          "title": "Document PR #$pr_number - ${title//\"/\'} $version",
          "body": "Determine whether #$pr_number needs any release notes or other documentation updates",
          "assignees": [ "$writer" ],
          "labels": [ "Area: Documentation" ]
      }
```

Currently, the title of the issue takes the title of the PR and changes instances of quotes(") to apostrophes(') and doesn't cause an issue (e.g. PR title: "Error returned" bug >>> Issue title: 'Error returned' bug). I would like to know how to take instances of apostrophes(') and delete them from the title (e.g. PR title: Don't enable xyz >>> Issue title: Dont enable xyz). I'm also open to other feedback on how to rework this issue as I'm not sure why the apostophe causes the workflow to fail in the first place.

I'm expecting this workflow to always create issues from merged PRs regardless of what the PR title's syntax or contents are.

Comment: I don't use yaml, but why not double-quote `title`, e.g. `title="${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}"`? If you need to prevent the `$` expansion, escape it, e.g. `title="\${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}"` (note: depending on the script language you may need to escape the `"\"` as well)

Comment: Why not pass `title` (and maybe the other values) as environment variables rather than by insertion?

Comment: You can use `tr` command i.e. `title="$(echo "$title" | tr -d "'")"`. IMHO, it's much better to have env vars for GHA contexts using `env` and use those in the `run` section. It's much cleaner and abstracts away the GHA related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like:

```
title="${title//\'/}"
```

do the trick?
Or delete both quotes *and* apostrophes:

```
title="${title//[\'\"]/}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin) for the comment you left. Your tip did the trick for me! Much thanks

His solution:

> I don't use YAML, but why not double-quote `title`, e.g. `title="${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}"`? If you need to prevent the `$`
> expansion, escape it, e.g. `title="\${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}"` (note: depending on the script
> language you may need to escape the `"\"` as well)

My changes:

```
 - name: create-issue
    id: create-issue
    run: |
      title="\${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}"

      echo "title should be ${title//[\'\"]/}"

      writer=${{ steps.get-writer.outputs.writer }}

      echo "writer should be $writer"

      echo "test"

      version="(v0.30)"

      pr_number=${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}

      data=$( cat << EOT
      {
          "title": "Document PR #$pr_number - {title//[\'\"]/} $version",
```