# How do I delete a backtick(`) in bash syntax for a GitHub Action Workflow?

Tags: bash, github-actions

My original problem is posted here: [How do I find/delete an apostrophe(') in bash syntax for a GitHub Action Workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76774858/how-do-i-find-delete-an-apostrophe-in-bash-syntax-for-a-github-action-workflo)

Since resolving this issue I've run into another and become quite stuck. Now, this GitHub action issue is failing if the PR title has a backtick in it.

Context:
In my organization, we have a GitHub Action that creates a new issue when a PR is merged into the main branch. The purpose of this issue is to determine whether or not the PR that merged needs updated user documentation.

The GitHub action lives in a yml file and uses bash syntax for the commands. My current command looks like this:

```
- name: create-issue
    id: create-issue
    run: |
      title="${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}"

      echo "title should be ${title//[\'\"]/}"

      writer=${{ steps.get-writer.outputs.writer }}

      echo "writer should be $writer"

      echo "test"

      pr_number=${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}

      data=$( cat << EOT
      {
          "title": "Document PR #$pr_number - ${title//[\'\"]/} $version",
          "body": "Determine whether #$pr_number needs any release notes or other documentation updates",
          "assignees": [ "$writer" ],
          "labels": [ "Area: Documentation" ]
      }
```

The current functionality takes the title of the PR and removes apostrophes and double-quotes. For example:

- PR title: "This is my 'PR' title"
- Created issue title: This is my PR title

However, the workflow now fails to run if there is a backtick in the PR title. For example:

- PR title: `This is my PR title`

I've tried a couple of ways to escape the backtick character to remove it when creating an issue but haven't had much luck. Generally I encounter a "unexpected end of file" error or a "bad substitution" error. I'm hoping to find a solution that removes the backticks entirely. Any and all feedback is welcome.

Comment: This is a serious design flaw in github actions; using string concatenation to generate source code is a security risk for exactly the reasons you're demonstrating (it causes data, like PR titles, to be parsed as source code), and they should never have designed it this way in the first place. My first instinct is to provide advice along the lines of "throw it out and use something that exposes variables via the environment or an input file in a structured or well-known format like JSON instead".

Comment: (Similarly, if you're doing it right and processing data in such a way that it's kept out-of-band from your code in the first place, there's no need to "sanitize" or remove any kind of character, and single or double quotes are just as legal and safe as anything else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Charles points out in the comments, and as GitHub themselves recommends [in their docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#understanding-the-risk-of-script-injections): as a rule of thumb, don't put *any* `${{...}}` expansions into the body of a `run` step. Instead, set the value in the environment, and then reference that environment variable:

```yaml
- name: create-issue
    id: create-issue
    env:
      title: ${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}
      writer: ${{ steps.get-writer.outputs.writer }}
      pr_number: ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}
    run: |
      echo "title should be $title"
      echo "writer should be $writer"
```

Comment: Wouldn't the run command still fail here despite defining the variables in env?

```
      data=$( cat << EOT
      {
          "title": "Document PR #$pr_number - $title $version",
          "body": "Determine whether #$pr_number needs any release notes or other documentation updates",
          "assignees": [ "$writer" ],
          "labels": [ "Area: Documentation" ]
      }
```

Comment: @mzbu That's more a matter of JSON escaping, which you might be able to get around with `toJSON(github.event.pull_request.title)` or similar.